# index.js file missing in openUI5 from Step 9: Component Configuration

Tags: sapui5

I am learning openui5 (Version 1.61.1) using openUI5 Documentation

From the version 1.61.1 openUI5 includes index.js file.This index.js file is missing in the documetation from "step:9 Component configuration " till the last step. I am unable to proceed further without index.js file.I am not sure whether i missed any point or its something related to documentation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. in step no 9 we have to include the below meta data tag and change onInit value in index.html file.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
```

However i am not sure why its working if we add this meta data tag. can anyone explain me.

Answer (score 1):

> I have found the issue. in step no 9 we have to include the below meta
>   data tag and change onInit value in index.html file.
>
> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
> data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
> ```

I had the same problem with step 9 of the tutorial. In addition to the suggested changes, I had also to change the body of the index.html to show the content of my view.

My working index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chatter UI</title>
    <script
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/openui5-demo/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-async="true"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
                "sap.ui.demo.walkthrough": "./"
            }'
            data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
    >
    </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
    <div data-sap-ui-component data-name="sap.ui.demo.walkthrough" data-id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```